# How to monitor a Sawtooth network in Docker containers?

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-sawtooth

I would like to monitor a Sawtooth network in Docker containers. I found this section "Using Grafana to Display Sawtooth Metrics" here https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/nightly/1-2/sysadmin_guide/grafana_configuration.html. However, there is a Note:"This procedure is for a Ubuntu environment. For a Sawtooth network in Docker containers, there are additional steps to change the configuration of the validator and REST API containers. This guide does not describe these steps". I cannot find anywhere a guide about monitoring a Sawtooth network in Docker containers and what are the additional steps which are referred. Does anybody know any guidance about this? Or any idea what are maybe the additional steps?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, this question is answered in other forums. Here is the discussion that you are interested in https://lists.hyperledger.org/g/sawtooth/topic/32607015. Please let us know if you would to know more on anything in particular.